# Fetching data when Modal loads in Next.js

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, next.js, fetch-api

I'm building some functionality in my application where a user can add a new project to a timesheet application.

The way I' trying to do this is by creating a Modal that contains a form. In the form, I have a Select field that should be populated with all existing users in the database. Thus, I tried to use the useEffect hook to fetch the data from an 'api' and then populate the Select field with the user names.

Below the code examples:

Main screen with button to open the Modal

```
import MainScreen from '../../../components/mainscreen';
import Table from '../../../components/table';

const ProjectOverview = () => {
  return(
    <MainScreen>
      <Table />
    </MainScreen>
  );
};

export default ProjectOverview;
```

Table.js

```
import ProjectCols from '../data/projectcols';
import DataTable from 'react-data-table-component';
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import Modal from './modal';
import ProjectForm from './forms/projectform';

const Table = () => {
  const [showModal, setShowModal] = useState(false);

  const data = [
    {
      id: 1,
      project: 'Test Project A',
      client: 'Customer A',
      pm: 'John Doe',
      active: true
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      project: 'Test Project B',
      client: 'Customer B',
      pm: 'Jane Doe',
      active: false
    }
  ];

  return (
    <div id='overview' className="bg-slate-100 h-screen w-full overflow-y-auto">
      <div className='flex justify-end h-20 w-3/4 m-auto'>
        <div className='flex space-x-2 h-full'>
          <button type='button' onClick={() => setShowModal(true)} className='self-center inline-block px-6 py-2.5 bg-green-500 text-white font-medium text-xs leading-tight uppercase rounded shadow-md hover:bg-green-600 hover:shadow-lg focus:bg-green-600 focus:shadow-lg focus:outline-none focus:ring-0 active:bg-green-700 active:shadow-lg transition duration-150 ease-in-out'>Add</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className='w-3/4 m-auto'>
        <DataTable 
          columns={ProjectCols} 
          data={data} //This will need to be retrieved from the database
          direction="auto"
          fixedHeaderScrollHeight="300px"
          pagination
          responsive
        />
      </div>
      <Modal onClose={() => setShowModal(false)} show={showModal} title='Create a new project'>
        <ProjectForm />
      </Modal>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Table;
```

Modal.js

```
const Modal = ({ show, onClose, children, title }) => {

  const handleCloseClick = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    onClose();
  };

  return ( show ? (
    <div tabIndex="-1" aria-hidden="true" className="overflow-y-auto fixed inset-0 bg-gray-600 bg-opacity-50 z-50 h-full w-full md:inset-0 md:h-full">
      <div className="relative top-20 p-4 mx-auto w-1/2 h-full md:h-auto">
        <div className="relative bg-white rounded-lg shadow dark:bg-gray-700">
          <button type="button" onClick={handleCloseClick} className="absolute top-3 right-2.5 text-gray-400 bg-transparent hover:bg-gray-200 hover:text-gray-900 rounded-lg text-sm p-1.5 ml-auto inline-flex items-center dark:hover:bg-gray-800 dark:hover:text-white">
            <svg aria-hidden="true" className="w-5 h-5" fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 20 20" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path fillRule="evenodd" d="M4.293 4.293a1 1 0 011.414 0L10 8.586l4.293-4.293a1 1 0 111.414 1.414L11.414 10l4.293 4.293a1 1 0 01-1.414 1.414L10 11.414l-4.293 4.293a1 1 0 01-1.414-1.414L8.586 10 4.293 5.707a1 1 0 010-1.414z" clipRule="evenodd"></path></svg>
            <span className="sr-only">Close modal</span>
          </button>
          <div className="py-6 px-6 lg:px-8">
            <h3 className="mb-4 text-xl font-medium text-center text-gray-900 dark:text-white">{title}</h3>
            {children}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div> 
  ) : null
  );
};

export default Modal;
```

select.js

```
const Select = ({ label, register, options }) => {
  return (
    <div className="flex items-center mt-5">
      <label className="w-1/4 block text-sm font-medium text-gray-900 dark:text-white">{label}</label>
      <select {...register('projectManager')} className="bg-gray-50 w-3/4 m-auto border border-gray-300 text-gray-900 sm:text-sm rounded-lg focus:ring-primary-600 focus:border-primary-600 block p-2.5 dark:bg-gray-700 dark:border-gray-600 dark:placeholder-gray-400 dark:text-white dark:focus:ring-blue-500 dark:focus:border-blue-500">
        {options.map(option => {
          return (
            <option key={option.id} value={option.id}>{option.name}</option>
          );
        }
        )}
      </select>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Select;
```

EDIT; Forgot to add the code that doesn't seem te work

projectform.js

```
import { useForm } from 'react-hook-form';
import Input from '../form-components/input';
import Button from '../form-components/button';
import Select from '../form-components/select';
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const ProjectForm = () => {
  const { register, handleSubmit } = useForm();
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('trigger');
    fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/user')
      .then((data) => {
        setData(data);
      });
  }, []);

  //   const users = [
  //     {id: 1, name: 'Piet Snot'},
  //     {id: 2, name: 'Stefano Gandolfo'}
  //   ];

  return (
    <form className='flex flex-col justify-around' onSubmit={handleSubmit((data) => console.log(data))}>
      <Input label='Project Name' register={register} required />
      <Select label='Project Manager' options={data} register={register}/>
      <Button name='Create' type='submit' onClick={() => console.log('Test')} />
    </form>
  );
};

export default ProjectForm;
```

I've been trying to get this thing solved over the past 2 days but just can't seem to find the issue.. All help would be greatly appreciated!

Cheers!

Comment: What exactly isn't working here, what errors/bugs are you getting

Comment: I think Is better to paste the code that doesn't works. This version use a static data and i suppose It works

Comment: Hi all, sorry that I forgot to add the piece of code that doesn't work. Rookie mistake! I've edited the original post and added the projectform.js code that contains the useEffect code that doesn't trigger....

Comment: Have you tried to set your data to an empty array initially in your ProjectForm component? `const [data, setData] = useState([]);`

Comment: Yes! Setting the data const to an empty array is half the solution! I also had to implement the solution mentioned by Gabriel to get it working, i.e. returning a json to get the data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) returns a [`Response`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response) object, and you need to run [`.json()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/json) (*in this case*) on it to get the data.

So

```
useEffect(() => {
    console.log('trigger');
    fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/user')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        setData(data);
      });
  }, []);
```

Comment: Thanks Gabriel! This worked for me. I also had to set the initial state of data to an empty array to get the useEffect hook triggered!